# nVidia GTX 650 doesn't display any output after installing drivers

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting, nvidia-geforce

I have a nVidia GTX 650 that works (displays video output) before installing the driver, albeit with limited resolutions and no Aero Glass theme effects etc.

When I install the driver, there is no video output coming from any of the card's connections (two DVI, one HDMI and one VGA).

I've done a 'clean' install of the latest nVidia driver each time I've tried this card with no other graphics cards installed in the machine.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit Service Pack 1.

I have a nVidia 8800 GT which I have been using before getting the 650 (the 8800 GT works fine) and when I install it alongside the GTX 650 and use its outputs I am able to get a picture on the display.

I checked the nVidia control panel's system information and the GTX 650 is detected and all of its information is shown correctly alongside the info for the 8800 GT.

Does anyone know if I can do anything to salvage this 650 or is it a lost cause?

Would updating the BIOS solve any issue that might cause this behaviour?

### Edit:

I just plugged an HDMI cable into the 650 while the computer was running and displaying from the 8800 GT, and it Blue Screened with the message: "Attempt to reset display driver and recover from timeout failed".

The nVidia Control Panel info:

[image: nVidia Control Panel Information]

Comment: What version of the driver are you trying to use exactly?  Are you removing the driver for the 8800GT before you attempt to install the 650?

Comment: @Ramhound Driver version is 320.18 - and yes, I removed the 8800GT before installing the 650 the first few times trying to get it to work.

Comment: You removed the drivers before you install the new graphics card?  Your screenshot indicates your system is aware of both devices.

Comment: @Ramhound I removed the drivers before installing the card - when no drivers are installed and the 650 is alone, I get output on the screen, but no 3d accleration (indicating pass-through only) - when I install the driver, nothing displays on screen - it is then that I reinstalled the 8800 alongside the 650 in order to get that screenshot. (The screenshot was taken with both the 8800GT and the 650 GTX installed in PCI-E slots in the system).

Comment: Well the driver is irrelevant, they both use the same one. When you have the 8800GT hooked up alongside the 650, what does it show in the PhysX/SLI configuration tab? I dunno though, if only having the 650 installed doesn't work, you might have a dead card. Also what power supply?

Comment: It's a 980W power supply - should be more than enough power, the card has LEDs on it to indicate if it has the correct power, when I plug it into the PCIe slot, the RED LED turns on, and then when I connect the 6-pin power connector, the LED turns GREEN. I don't have it installed right now to check the PhysX/SLI tab, but I'll get back to you as soon as I can.